# Tkinter: How to detect screen size and change text size of Labels?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two questions about Tkinter:

1. Is there a way to detect the size of the used screen and adapat the GUI display according to this parameter?
2. How can I change text size in Tkinter in labels?

Comment: `root.winfo_screenwidth()` and `root.winfo_screenheight()`

Answer (score 3):

For screen size:

```
import Tkinter as tk
x = tk.Tk()
print(x.winfo_screenwidth(), x.winfo_screenheight())
```

For text size:

```
import tkFont

...
f = tkFont.Font(size=100)
label = tk.Label(self, text='Big text', font=f)
....
```

To adjust text size to screen size you just need to come up with some kind of font scaling algorithm that will convert `winfo_screenwidth` and `winfo_screenheight` to appropriate `size` value of `tkFont.Font`.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in a comment, you can use the window methods `winfo_screenwidth()` & `winfo_screenheight()` to find the size of your display. To change the text size for labels, simply edit the `font` config option for `Label` widgets.

The `font` can be changed using simple string values (to change one parameter of the font, like size or font face), or it can be given a `tuple` of string values to edit multiple parameters. You can see an example of how to use this, as well as the window methods, in my example:

Example:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk() 

#Center widget: Half screen dimension - half window dimension
root.geometry("350x150+%d+%d" %( ( (root.winfo_screenwidth() / 2.) - (350 / 2.) ), ( (root.winfo_screenheight() / 2.) - (150 / 2.) ) ) )
l = Label(root, font = ('consolas', '20', 'italic'), text = "This is a label", justify = CENTER).pack(pady = (50, 0))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What it is the purpose of such a calculus in your root geometrt method?

Comment: I used that to center the screen; I chose an arbitrary size for the window width/height (350x150). Then I chose (half of the screen width - half of the window width) for the x pos, and similarly (half of the screen height - half of the window height) for the y pos. This puts the window (relatively) in the center of the screen. The y position usually isn't centered as this doesn't factor in the border around the window.